# Nginx Ingress Controller trailling slash with HTTPS redirect

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, http-status-code-308

Nginx Ingress Controller trailling slash with HTTPS redirect

I'm trying to redirect requests from HTTP to HTTPS using an Ingress with Nginx Ingress Controller. My app is written in Django v3.0.7, my Nginx Controller is v0.46.0 and k8s v1.19.8.

I have the following ingress:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: INGRESS-NAME
  namespace: INGRESS-NS
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /api/v1/$1/
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "ISSUER-NAME"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/permanent-redirect-code: '308'
spec:
  tls:
  ...
  rules:
  - host: MY-DOMAIN
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /api/v1/?(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: SVC-NAME
            port:
              number: SVC-PORT
```

Requests at `https://.../api/v1/get-token/`, raise this error:

`[05/May/2021:20:39:49 +0000] "POST /api/v1/get-token// HTTP/1.1" 404` => POST get an extra `/` at the end. But the same request with HTTP or `https://.../api/v1/get-token` (no trailing `/`) is fine.

If I remove the

```
annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /api/v1/$1/
```

The redirect removes trailing `/` and it causes POST to turn into GET in all HTTP POST request causing an 403 - Method not allowed as shown in Nginx Logs:

```
[05/May/2021:20:54:52 +0000] "POST /api/v1/get-token HTTP/1.1" 308 164
[05/May/2021:20:54:53 +0000] "POST /api/v1/get-token HTTP/1.1" 301 0 
[05/May/2021:20:54:53 +0000] "GET /api/v1/get-token/ HTTP/1.1" 405
```

but HTTP POST request works fine with `http://.../api/v1/get-token//` (two trailing `/`).

Is there a way to solve this problem? The 308 HTTP -> HTTPS redirect is important, so I can't remove it, but is there a way to force requests to have one, and only one, trailing `/`? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried removing just a trailing `/` from `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /api/v1/$1/`?

Comment: Yes, but what happens is the second case, only `http://.../api/v1/get-token//` works.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems here

## Problem #1

```yaml
annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /api/v1/$1/
```

causes requests sent to `https://.../api/v1/get-token/` to end with *HTTP 404 Not Found*, but `https://.../api/v1/get-token` woks fine.

**Why?**
Because trailing `/` at the end of `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /api/v1/$1/` rewrite is added to the URL, and `/api/v1/get-token//` leads to a resource that does not exist.

**What to do about it?**
Change `path` key to `/api/v1/?(.*\b)/`. I'm not 100% sure it will work, but it's worth a try.
*or*
Remove trailing `/` from rewrite.
Now, doing that causes problem #2.

---

## Problem #2

Requests to `https://.../api/v1/get-token` ends with *405 Method Not Allowed*.

**Why?**
First redirection works fine (*HTTP 308*), however request is redirected again with *HTTP 301*.

MDN article on HTTP 301 states:

> Even if the specification requires the method (and the body) not to be altered when the redirection is performed, not all user-agents align with it - you can still find this type of bugged software out there. It is therefore recommended to use the 301 code only as a response for GET or HEAD methods and to use the 308 Permanent Redirect for POST methods instead, as the method change is explicitly prohibited with this status.

Basically *HTTP 301* causes `POST` to become `GET`, and `GET` is not allowed, hence *HTTP 405*.

**What to do about it?**
Make sure not to redirect requests twice, especially with *HTTP 301*.

Comment: I'll try the first ideia and let you know, but about the second one: how can I not redirect twice? Seems like it's default behavior for Nginx Ingress Controller somehow. As a matter of fact, I really don't want to redirect twice because it make POST turn to GET as stated by the article above. For some reason, Nginx redirects with 308 and then again 301.

Comment: The first option (path key `/api/v1/?(.*\b)/`) falls into the second problem if I don't remove the `/ ` from rewrite.If removed, nothing works anymore. What I'm using right now is no rewrite, path `/api/v1/?(.*)` and this config:

`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      if ($request_uri ~ "^[^?]*?//") {
        rewrite "^" $scheme://$host$uri permanent;
      }`

It's allowing only https with `/`, it's not ideal since I wanted all for possibilities, but I can work with this for now.

Comment: Hi @ToledoNeto, did you solve your problem?

Comment: no, nothing new so far except that "solution" in my last comment. It works, but would be nice to have something better.